# c# .net Method with differing inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Forgive my ignorance if this is 'a basic question'.....

I have a method that needs to be able to accept differing numbers and types of inputs. Eg

```
protected void example(int iVar, string sVar)
```

&/or

```
protected voide example(int iVar, string sVar, double dVar)
```

Putting aside questions/comments such as "Why????", is there an easy / shorthand way of doing this without writing the method twice?

Any help &/or pointers will be very greatfully received.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One option is optional arguments. Reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make your last parameter an [optional argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) (C# 4.0 and above):

```
protected void example(int iVar, string sVar, double dVar = 0.0)
```

Alternatively, the implementation of the first method could simply call the second:

```
protected void example(int iVar, string sVar)
{
    example(iVar, sVar, 0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set default values for parameters that will be used if nothing is supplied

```
protected void example(int iVar, string sVar, double dVar = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you looking more on [Named and Optional Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

These provide you more flexibility on method/delegate/constructor arguments and COM interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use optional parameters:

```
protected void example(int? iVar, string? sVar, double? dVar = 0)
```